# Google map APIs in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Just wanted to know if we can use Google maps in Windows Phone 8 instead of the default Nokia maps. Is there anyone who has tried it?

Answer (score 3):

So when you search for a property just to switch the Nokia map data with the Google one, then no, that's not possible. The Nokia maps are maps in vector format. And the engine is integrated into the operating system.

But there are ways to show Google maps or build a maps application with Google data on your own of course.

1) Map/Tile-Hybrid: Use the map control and use the tile source/map tile layer on top to overlay the map control with the tiles from google maps REST API. 
An example for WP7 (in WP8 it's similar) is here:
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/06/14/Display_Google_Maps_Imagery_using_Bing_Maps_Silverlight_Control.aspx

2) Standalone maps app: here you need to do it completely on your own. You should create a DeepZom/ MultiScale class that loads the tiles via the deepzoom mechanisms automatically from the Google REST API. See details about the technology here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#loading_a_deep_zoom_image

Comment: It's possible with old map control, but I have a memory leak with old map control in WP8..